# android studio: AVD Nexus_5 is already running

Tags: java, android-studio, avd

Nao consigo rodar o AVD pois aparece a mensagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ja tentei deletar a pasta abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguem sabe o que devo fazer?

Comment: Coloque para mostrar arquivos ocultos no windows, caso apareça o arquivo **.lock** delete-o.

Comment: provavelmente era um processo que ficou travado.